# Background image present but not visible

Tags: html, css, image, url

On the following site http://haircolourideas.eu/#section2 I have a ul in the services section and the li's have background images . The li's have classes of service1 , service2 etc. The background images have suddenly become invisible . If I inspect element the css is correct and it shows that the images are present . The site has been live a couple of months and without me changing anything this has just happened today

```
<ul id="services-list" class="hidden">
    <li class="service1 service-img"><label class="btn" for="modal-1"><h3>meche</h3></label></li>
    <li class="service2 service-img"><label class="btn" for="modal-2"><h3>tinting</h3></label></li>
    <li class="service3 service-img"><label class="btn" for="modal-3"><h3>fashion</h3></label></li>
    <li class="service4 service-img"><label class="btn" for="modal-4"><h3>change</h3></label></li>
</ul>

.service1 {
    background: url(../img/meche1.png);
    cursor: pointer;
}

.service2 {
    background: url(../img/tint1.png);
    cursor: pointer;
}

.service3 {
    background: url(../img/fashion1.png);
    cursor: pointer;
}

.service4 {
    background: url(../img/change1.png);
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Im not sure but it seems to be you have a class="hidden" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the animation doesn't function because in the `ul` you have `class="hidden"` which makes `opacity: 0` that hides all the `ul` section. The `class="hidden"` is applied because you are missing this script in your server jquery.viewportchecker.js. If you open your console with inspect element you can see the error. The script makes the class hidden apply or not based on the section you are. In some way the script got deleted from your server as you can see in the link: http://haircolourideas.eu/js/jquery.viewportchecker.js so you had to put it back and with that also this jquery error:
"Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).addClass(...).viewportChecker is not a function"
 in you console will disappear and the website will function as before

Comment: i'm a little new to this so just wondering how does a jquery file just get deleted from the server?

Comment: I don't know what to say for sure but you could have made changes on your web by entering on your host cpanel and deleted it accidentally, or you made a backup and restore and has lost in this process. Have you made any changes on your web or changed the host ?

Comment: no all i had done was update my css folder which is nowhere near my js folder but either way i've learned that if i encounter problems i should check out the various folders on my server

Comment: Yeah the problem could be anywhere and to be more specific you should check for information about your specific server.

Answer (score 2):

Remove class hidden from thoes nodes:

```
<div id="services-info" class="hidden">
<ul id="services-list" class="hidden">
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<ul id="services-list" class="hidden">
<li class="service1 service-img"><label class="btn" for="modal-1"><h3>meche</h3></label></li>
<li class="service2 service-img"><label class="btn" for="modal-2"><h3>tinting</h3></label></li>
<li class="service3 service-img"><label class="btn" for="modal-3"><h3>fashion</h3></label></li>
<li class="service4 service-img"><label class="btn" for="modal-4"><h3>change</h3></label></li>
```

Remove the `class="hidden"` from your `ul`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this: i can say surely show your image.

```
.hidden {
    /* opacity: 0; */
}
```

> If don't need then remove `opacity:0` property, otherwise set
>   opacity: 1;

Otherwise You can remove **hidden** class from ul

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the class hidden means

```
<ul id="services-list" class="hidden"> not visible
<ul id="services-list" class=""> visible
```